# Handle differently GET and POST during OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

During the `OnActionExecuting` method, some processing are made which could lead to a redirection to the home page.

But in Ajax POST calls, these processing will definitely fail. Calls are made by a grid from Kendo UI, so I have no control on them.

So I want this method handles in two different ways if calls are `GET` and `POST`.

I tried :

```
[HttpGet]
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // Do something
}

[HttpPost]
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

But it does work.
I can't find a Property like `IsPostBack` in WebFroms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ActionExecutingContext` has a `HttpContext` property. From there, you can obtain the `Request` property, which has a `HttpMethod` property

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   if(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
   {
      // Do nothing
   }
   else
   {
       //Do Something
   }
}
```

Comment: I used 'bool isPost = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.Equals("POST", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);'. I think it is uglier than a native boolean, but it works. I was looking around HttpContext, but in the wrong place. Thanks.